# could anyone tell me whats wrong in this code?

Tags: c, compiler-errors

The problem is just to find the greatest of the three numbers .
I'm pretty sure about it but the system shows 'Thread 1 ;breakpoint 2.1'
PS: I'm using xcode .....
Thank You!

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()   {

    int a ;
    int b ;
    int c ;

    printf("Enter your first number\n") ;
    scanf("%d",&a) ;

    printf("Enter your second number\n") ;
    scanf("%d",&b);

    printf("Enter your third number\n") ;
    scanf("%d",&c) ;

    if (a>b & a>c) {
        printf("%d is greatest\n",a) ;
    }
    if (b>a & b>c) {
        printf("%d is greatest\n",b);
    }
    if (c>a & c>b) {
        printf("%d is greatest\n",c);
    }
    return 0 ;


}
```

Comment: `(a>b & a>c)` -> `(a>b && a>c)`. Logical and operator = `&&`.  A single `&` is a bit and operator.

Comment: `&` and `&&` are two different operators. You used the wrong one.

Comment: How do you build your program? How do you run it? What input do you give it? What is the full and complete and unedited output (copy-paste it as text)?

Comment: `if (b>a & b>c)` -> `else if (b>c)` & `if (c>a & c>b)` -> `else` , just to take into account the user entering the same number twice and prevent unnecessary evaluation.

Answer (score 1):

Use logical `&&` insted of bitwise `&`.

```
if (a>b && a>c)
```

Answer (score 1):

You want to use `&&` but you are using `&` instead.

`if (a>b && a>c)`